# How to clean hoverboard wheels

Tags: cleaning

Please help! I accidentally ran over some poop its dried up and stuck to my wheels! Can't take it off I tried a bunch of stuff to try and clean it but didn't work! Any help appreaciated!

Comment: You found the world's only non-water-soluable poop?

Comment: @Melonlink It would be grateful if you provide some pictures of the situation.

Comment: This puzzles me: how can it be a HOVERboard if it has wheels?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the wheel under water for a while.

Then try with these nylon brush:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mendapump.com](http://documents.mendapump.com/Images/Catalog/35689.jpg))</sub>

Comment: A little soap or detergent (dish soap for hand washing dishes, for instance) along with the water will help, but soaking is a prerequisite if the "stuff" has dried out and hasn't yet reached the "crumbly dust" stage (which it might not if it stays dry).